# Resolving a Bug in My Code which is not passing the test cases

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

There is this problem on Leetcode , Link of the problem is : https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-time-for-given-digits/

I have written the code for this problem , and according to me my code is correct but still my code is not passing all the test cases and I am stuck debugging where is the issue in my Code .

Can Anybody please help me with this ?

```
class Solution {
public:
    
bool isValid(string s){
    if(s[0] > '2') return false;
    if(s[0] == '2'){
        if(s[1] >= '4'){
            return false ;
        }
    }
    
    if(s[2] >=6) return false ;
    
    return true ; 
    
}

vector<vector<int>> permute(vector<int> &nums)
{
    vector<vector<int>> result;
    //Base Case For The Problem:
    if (nums.size() <= 1)
        return {nums};

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<int> v(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        v.erase(v.begin() + i);
        auto res = permute(v);

        for (int j = 0; j < res.size(); j++)
        {
            vector<int> _v = res[j];
            _v.insert(_v.begin(), nums[i]);
            result.push_back(_v);
        }
    }

    return result;
    
    
}
    
    
    string largestTimeFromDigits(vector<int>& A) {
        vector<vector<int>> res ;
        vector<string> valid ; //For Only Storing the Valid Time Permutations
       
        res = permute(A); 
        
        //Now , Iterating Over All the Permutations:
        for(int i=0 ; i<res.size() ; i++){
           string curr = "";
            for(int j=0 ; j<res[i].size() ; ++j){
                curr += res[i][j];
            }
            if(isValid(curr)) valid.push_back(curr);
            
        }
        sort(valid.begin() , valid.end()); 
        
        string ans = ""; //The Final Answer that we have to return at the end.
        
        if(valid.size() > 0){
            //Now , perform the Required Operations:
            string temp = valid[valid.size() - 1];
            ans = temp.substr(0,2) + ":" + temp.substr(2);
        }
        
        return ans; 
        
        
        
    }
};
```

Comment: Are there any sample test cases? Please show them and the result of your code for them. Have you invented some test cases of your own? Please show them and the result of your code for them.

Comment: Does a correct time contain a ":"? Where? In `s[2]`maybe?

Comment: Pleasae provide a [mre] of your code being tested with a few of your test cases.

Comment: *according to me my code is correct*  -- FYI, that looks like a lot of code to solve such a simple problem.

Comment: do you have any test case that your code does pass? I didnt find any: https://godbolt.org/z/GhaTW3

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein What's the other alternative then apart from permutations ?

Comment: @idclev No my code is not passing any test case .

Answer (score 2):

Two problems in your code, both related to mixing `int` with `char`. The first is here:

```
if(s[2] >=6 ) {
    return false ;
}
```

Because of this condition your `isValid` returns `false` always. No character in the range `'0'`...`'9'` is smaller than the integer `6`. Compare the `char` to a `char`:

```
if(s[2] >='6' ) {
    return false ;
}
```

Next, here

```
 curr += res[i][j];
```

`res[i][j]` is an integer, but you want to add a character to the string:

```
 curr += static_cast<char>(res[i][j]) + '0';
```

After fixing those two I get expected output at least for input `{2,2,2,2}`, see here: https://godbolt.org/z/35r3f9.

I have to mention that you would have found those problems yourself if you had used a debugger. Getting better in coding is not that much about making less mistakes, but about getting better at finding and fixing them. The debugger is an essential tool to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I Got my Mistake Now

Answer (score 0):

#### C++

You can use `std::prev_permutation` and sort first:

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();

// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

static const struct Solution {
    static const std::string largestTimeFromDigits(std::vector<int>& A) {
        std::sort(std::begin(A), std::end(A), std::greater<int>());

        do if (
                (A[0] < 2 || A[0] == 2 && A[1] < 4) &&
                A[2] < 6
            ) {
                return std::to_string(A[0]) + std::to_string(A[1]) + ":" + std::to_string(A[2]) + std::to_string(A[3]);
            }

        while (std::prev_permutation(std::begin(A), std::end(A)));

        return "";
    }
};
```

Here is LeetCode's official solution in C++:

```
class Solution {
public:
    string largestTimeFromDigits(vector<int>& A) {

        int max_time = -1;
        // prepare for the generation of permutations next.
        std::sort(A.begin(), A.end());

        do {
            int hour = A[0] * 10 + A[1];
            int minute = A[2] * 10 + A[3];

            if (hour < 24 && minute < 60) {
                int new_time = hour * 60 + minute;
                max_time = new_time > max_time ? new_time : max_time;
            }
        } while(next_permutation(A.begin(), A.end()));

        if (max_time == -1) {
            return "";
        } else {
            std::ostringstream strstream;
            strstream << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << max_time / 60
               << ":" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << max_time % 60;
            return strstream.str();
        }
    }
};
```

#### Alternative solution with regular expression:

This'd be difficult in C++ though:

```
class Solution:
    def largestTimeFromDigits(self, A: List[int]) -> str:
        for i in range(2359, -1, -1):
            if i < 1000:
                i = format(i, '04')

            if int(re.findall(r'\d{2}$', str(i))[0]) > 59:
                continue

            l = list(map(int, str(i)))
            for j in A:
                if j in l:
                    l.remove(j)
            if len(l) == 0:
                hm = re.findall(r'.{2}', str(i))
                return f'{hm[0]}:{hm[1]}'

        return ""
```

#### Alternative solution using three loops in Java:

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final String largestTimeFromDigits(
        final int[] A
    ) {
        String res = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 4; ++k) {
                    if (i == j || i == k || j == k) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    String hour = "" + A[i] + A[j];
                    String minute = "" + A[k] + A[6 - i - j - k];
                    String time = hour + ":" + minute;

                    if (
                        hour.compareTo("24") < 0 &&
                        minute.compareTo("60") < 0 &&
                        res.compareTo(time) < 0
                    ) {
                        res = time;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-time-for-given-digits/discuss/) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.